# Removing forced tags in titles as legitimate edit reason

Tags: discussion

[My edit removing a tag from a title got rejected as unhelpful](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15465101). Is removing a forced tag off the title of a post not a legitimate reason to edit? [StackExchange is explicitly against unhelpful tags in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/229097), so I thought I was helping to maintain community standards.

Here is a photo of the edit below for those who don't have enough rep:
[image: rejected_edit]

Comment: If I were reviewing your edit, I would have accepted it.

Comment: Given the number of views this question gets, I would have accepted the edit, the same edit on a question that got few views, I would have rejected as being a waist of time.

Comment: @IanRingrose Just wondering, why aren't low view questions as important? Aren't low view questions more likely to be the ones that this site wants to support (i.e., expert level / difficult, specific questions)? [Is popularity both bad and good?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/01/31/the-trouble-with-popularity/) Is it more important for SO to be a more comprehensive archive, or is SO deliberately targeting the low hanging fruit?

Comment: @IanRingrose im curious, what makes accepting a waste of time? I would assume it takes the same amount of button presses?

Comment: You probably could have made further improvements to the post such as changing italic *dict* to code `dict` and removing the [tag:get], [tag:set] tags and possibly some other things. But overall that is a reason to "Improve Edit" not "Reject".

Comment: If an edit is good but not complete, such as removing a tag on the title and grammar mistakes but not the salutations; I'll reject it if the propose edit is small or improve it if it has many changes that are worth keeping. From my POV, an edit just for score purposes (quickly done and not finished) is not worth it. That being said, I would have approved yours.

Comment: @Hoi_A,  lots of small edits that don't complete the job on questions that get few views are not worth it, hence, not approving to discourage even more of them.    But even a small incomplete improvement to a question with many views is worth it.   The issues is the "waste of time" if the person then does 101 other edits, not the time on the edit I am looking at, and have also "spent" the time on.

Comment: @Hoi_A, this edit is not needed to make the question useful, but correcting the spelling in a title is useful on a question with few views if there is any chance it will result in someone using google finding it.

Comment: @IanRingrose I see where you are coming from now, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @Hoi_A Note that opposite is true too - "correcting" spelling mistakes/words in title will make question harder to find for frequently visited questions (like linked one). It is hard to predict why this is the question people visit more often compared to similar sounding once. Editing question with 10K+ views should be done with great care...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, google gets told the number of votes each question has,  maybe it gets so many views due to google thinking it is good based on the votes.   Maybe it gets so many votes because it gets so many views....